# Error when trying to upload an Image to Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-dependencies

I am attempting to upload an image file (that I from the image picker), to Firebase Storage. I'm a little new to this and the examples I found when searching all seem to be of older versions of the plugin, so maybe that has something to do with it.
I'd really appreciate it, if someone could take a look at my code and let me know where I am going wrong.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Future uploadFile() async {
firebase_storage.Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref()
    .child('chats/${Path.from(_image.path)}}');
UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(_image);
await uploadTask;
print('File Uploaded');
storageReference.getDownloadURL().then((fileURL) {
  setState(() {
    print("UPOADED FILE URL IS: ${fileURL}");
    // _uploadedFileURL = fileURL;
  });
});
```

}

The error I am receiving is :

Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Path'

Many thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: You should also not passing the Path.from as String, instead just use its [path](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-io/File/path.html) property directly as it's a String getter, like this:

```
'chats/${_image.path}'
```

Try this:

```
print("UPOADED FILE URL IS: ${fileURL.toString()}");
```

Also, you have extra } in the StorageReference but it's not causing the problem.

Comment: Hi, the error is before the print statement you mention. It is not performing the upload task.

Comment: Try the edit I've added to my answer. passing _image.path directly not Path.from